# Go - Mock http.Response body with a file

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a Go function which performs a call to an external service. Here's the function:

```
func (gs *EuGameService) retrieveGames(client model.HTTPClient) (model.EuGamesResponse, error) {
   req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, gs.getGamesEndpoint, nil)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("Error while creating request ", err)
      return nil, err
   }

   resp, err := client.Do(req)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal("Error while retrieving EU games", err)
       return nil, err
   }

   var euGames model.EuGamesResponse
   decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
   decoder.Decode(&euGames)

   return euGames, nil
}
```

to properly test it, I'm trying to inject a mock client.

```
type HTTPClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

type mockClient struct{}

func (mc *mockClient) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    mock, _ := os.Open("../stubs/eugames.json")
    defer mock.Close()

    r := ioutil.NopCloser(bufio.NewReader(mock))

    return &http.Response{
        Status:     string(http.StatusOK),
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Body:       r,
    }, nil
}
```

the file `eugames.json` contains a couple of games. But for some reason, the body is always empty! What am I missing here? I tried to use a constant with the file content and it works, games are decoded correctly. So I'm assuming there's a problem with my use of the file.

Comment: You're defer-closing the file, the code attempting to read the response body will not be able to read from a closed file.

Comment: @mkopriva you're right. I'm a beginner with Go: should I copy the content in, let's say, a byte slice and create a reader from that slice?

Comment: ... you should be able to fix it with something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/Tu-Ka-DKkwY (the closefile method is not really necessary, but then, if I remember correctly, you won't be able to `defer mc.f.Close()` before the file's initialized, i.e. before calling `retrieveGames` which initializes it.)

Comment: Reading the file into a buffer and using that as the body is just as good, if not better.

Comment: Just a note: You can read the whole response from disk with net/http.ReadResponse. This is very convenient for testing.